# AWS API Gateway error: API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role as S3 proxy

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

There are similar questions but they have answers that I have tried.
I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong but any help would appreciated.

Test details:
[image]

The Error from a method-execution test; PUT request:

```
Execution log for request test-request
Mon Oct 16 10:13:47 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Mon Oct 16 10:13:47 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: PUT, Resource Path: /pop-data-xmlz/test.xml
Mon Oct 16 10:13:47 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {item=test.xml, folder=pop-data-xmlz}
Mon Oct 16 10:13:47 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Mon Oct 16 10:13:47 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {Content-Type=application/xml}
Mon Oct 16 10:13:47 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations: <test>
test string
</test>
Mon Oct 16 10:13:47 UTC 2017 : Request validation succeeded for content type application/json
Mon Oct 16 10:13:47 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role
Mon Oct 16 10:13:47 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 500
```

I am following the API Gateway To S3 tutorial (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) and attempting to execute a PUT request.

The API Gateway is in us-east-1 and the S3 bucket in us-east-2.

The created Role: **APIGatewayProxyCustom**

A policy (pop-date-ingest) is attached that allows PUT request to S3 buckets.
[image]

The Role has a trust relationship set:
[image]

Answer (score 153, accepted):

To fix this, go to the definition of your Role in the IAM and select the **Trust Relationships** tab. From here edit the policy and for the *Principal Service* add in `apigateway.amazonaws.com` as seen below.

This will grant the **API Gateway** the ability to assume roles to run your function in addition to the existing Lambda permission.

```js
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": ["apigateway.amazonaws.com","lambda.amazonaws.com"]
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Stopped me from going insane. Once again the official docs don't mention this, very bad on their part!

Comment: you are welcome @CliveSargeant. Good to know it helps :)

Comment: Thank you @VijayanathViswanathan. Very helpful.

Comment: But in question I see Trust Relationship with the same JSON.

Comment: Thank you very helpful for AWS Educate Users!

Comment: If not for helpful answers like this that fill in where AWS dropped the ball.... thank you so very much.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich the difference (at least for me) was to add the square brackets in service, around "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

Comment: Almost 2 hours figured out why and this is the answer !! Tq